# Getting time format from device settings when app resumed on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a solution on how to retrieve the up-to-date time format from the device settings when the app is resumed. For example, let's consider a scenario where I start my app with a 24-hour format and then send it to the background without closing it. Next, I navigate to my device settings and switch the time format to 12-hour. Upon returning to my app, I still receive the time format in 24-hour. However, if I send the app to the background once again and reopen it, it displays the time format correctly as 12-hour. It seems that the changes are only reflected when I resume the app for the second time. I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can obtain the updated time format during the first app resume?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.resumed),
    );
  }

@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      bool is24Hours = MediaQuery.of(context).alwaysUse24HourFormat;
    }
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Does this happen on iOS or Android? Or both?

Comment: @OlegBezr it happens both on iOS and on Android

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I managed to replicate the bug on my devices. It seems that there's a problem within PlatformDispatcher that can't be easily fixed. There are some related issues on GitHub that are still open